# More/Less effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do they make the "Tell me more" effect on the website provided below. I've read about read more/less effect in jQuery, but what I find interesting with that site is the page cannot be scrolled unless that button is clicked.

[Effect link](https://www.crazyegg.com/)

Comment: learn scrollTop

Comment: you can use CSS `overflow:hidden` and `overflow:auto` (after button click use jQuery to alter overflow CSS property of the `<body>` then use `animate()` for `scrollTop` property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this snippet helps you for the effect.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $("body").addClass("scroll");
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".goto").offset().top
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  height: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body.scroll{
  overflow: auto;
}
.goto{
  margin-top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Goto section</button>
<div class="goto">
Section
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Also is it possible to make it work on mobile devices?

Answer (score 1):

You can use html anchor instead, even the given site's link has used the same

Like this

```
<style>
  #header_div {
      height: 100vh; //fit to screen's height
  }

  #more_info_div {
      height: 100vh; 
  }
</style>

<div id="header_div">--content--</div>
<div id="more_info_div">--content--</div>
```

Use `#` before your div id in `href` to take to that particular div, like this

`<a href="#more_info_div" >Click me</a>`

you can give transition and other effects through css